# Auto scroll listbox wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scroll

I have a listbox of many richtextboxex in it.
Now I want to enable an auto scrolling feature for it.
I can't just do `listBox.SelectedIndex++;`in a timer or somthing, because then it will just go to the other richtextbox and I don't want that.
I'd like somthing more like this

```
sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset + 5);
```

which works perfectly in scroll view, can I implement the same thing to a listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found what I was looking for

```
            ScrollViewer sv = ((VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBox, 0) as FrameworkElement).FindName("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer);
        sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset + 0.004);
```

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like [Linq To Visual Tree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) you can get at the ScrollViewer inside the ListBox and then call ScrollToVerticalOffset on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here you should give the item index it automatically scrolls to the item

```
 list.ScrollIntoView(object item);
```

Comment: But that is completely not what I was looking for. I want to scroll the page not to a particular item but rather to a point on the window, as in the example I gave for scroll view